# how to use array within array in data function of d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I want to create rectangles on the screen using the x1,y1,x2,y2 coordinates in d3. the structure of my data is as below,

```
[
  {
    "tname":abc,
    "thours":200,
    "x1":10,
    "y1":10,
    "x2":10,
    "y2":10,
    "ttask":[
      {
        "pname":one,
        "phours":200,
        "pteam":abc,
        "px1":10,
        "py1":10,
        "px2":10,
        "py2":10
      },
      {
        "pname":two,
        "phours":200,
        "pteam":abc,
        "px1":10,
        "py1":10,
        "px2":10,
        "py2":10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tname":xyz,
    "thours":200,
    "x1":10,
    "y1":10,
    "x2":10,
    "y2":10,
    "ttask":[
      {
        "pname":one,
        "phours":200,
        "pteam":xyz,
        "px1":10,
        "py1":10,
        "px2":10,
        "py2":10
      },
      {
        "pname":two,
        "phours":200,
        "pteam":xyz,
        "px1":10,
        "py1":10,
        "px2":10,
        "py2":10
      } 
    ]
  }
]
```

in above data I want to create rectangle using px1, px2, py1,py2.

I tried multiple combinations of using data function but i could not achieve it

```
    var group = svg.selectAll('g')
         .data(teams);
    var rect = group.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d,i){
            return d.ttask;
        });
```

this is my last try. I am not sure how the data function treats the my input.

Please help me to understand how can I draw rect for each ttask array element using the data function.

Comment: All of the values for `px1, px2, py1, py2` are the same... Can you explain how you would want them to draw a rect?

Comment: Those are intentionally same, my intention here is to explain structure of my data. In real those co-ordinates will have appropriate values to form a rectangle. Using data and enter function I want to create rect and some text in rect.